# Facebook Like on HTTPS

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I did full blown research and I cannot find a way to solve my issue.  I lost a lot of likes when I switched my website from http to https, because apparently facebook thinks its a different URL, but that's not the problem.

Now I realize that the like button does not even work - all other ones do, but the main one for https://www.findyournet.com is not operational.  I checked it on the debugger and I get no errors, but when I click to like the page it fails.

Is https not permitted for facebook likes? Has anybody ever encountered this?  Here is the link to the problematic page: https://www.findyournet.com/facebook/like.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 1):

Edit (previous response deleted):

I'm not sure why it isn't working but here is a workaround:

Change your Like button code to this (only the URL is different)

```
<fb:like href="http://o-e.us/e.php?o=p43c" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```

I had trouble with like buttons/open graph tags when I was just starting as a developer so I made this tool: [Facebook Like Button Generator](http://o-e.us/fb/lbg)

I used the values in your open graph tags from https://www.findyournet.com so they should be exactly the same. My tool is pretty much a link shortener with custom open graph field setting and it will redirect back to whichever link you want it to (without the facebook crawler/bot knowing).

It worked for me, give it a shot :)

Comment: No, I actually saw the confirm link, that's why I changed the background.  Even if you confirm it, it will still not increase the like count.  I have played with it for quite a while and different facebook accounts - they all react the same way.  I've seen this happen before and I was able to fix it by going to the debugger, which would reset the like buttons somehow and they would start working, but this is not the case for a website with https.

Comment: I changed the color, so that the "confirm" link is visible again.  No matter what the count 456 stays there.